# jquery div scrolls up on click function fade/slide toggle

Tags: jquery, scroll, slide

Hy,

I have a problem. I created a fixed navigation bar so the middle content slides under it.
i made a div that, with jquery, opens by fading or sliding another div.
The problem is that the 1st div scrolls under the fixed div and i want it to remain to the initial position.
here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttondiv").click(function(){
        $("#content").slideToggle(1000);

    });
});
```

THANK YOU!